# Iterate through indexed property in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, properties, rtti, indexed

In Delphi 2010 is there a way to iterate through any kind of indexed property (like Pages of TPageControl, for example)?

Comment: @TLame `ActivePageIndex` is not an indexed property.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment, quite offensive by the way... I didn't say anything about ActivePageIndex, I don't know where you saw it. I said Pages.

Comment: I presume you are referring to the deleted comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, as there is not standard pattern that:

- specifies the index type
- specifies the start and end values of the index to use

That's why certain classes have enumerators: it is the pattern that tells the for ... in statement how to enumerate it.

What you can do however is a best estimate:

- most times the index is integer
- most times the index starts at zero
- most times there is a property Count or Length that tells you how to obtain the end value

Finally, it is possible to ["retrofit" TPageControl with a GetEnumertor using class helpers](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/04/22/delphi-adding-for-in-support-to-tpagecontrol/) (or record helpers if the underlying type is a record).

Comment: I did see your post (good stuff) while I was searching on the internet, trying to find an answer for this :) In my case, I have half dozen indexed properties of different components. I iterate through them just to get a "Caption" property. So, right now, I have half a dozen almost identical loops, and I don't like that. Although the GetEnumerator thing is cool, that's too much code for such a small problem.

Comment: What about abstracing those loops into some generic code, then pass an anonymous method to it that has contains the non-identical code?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to iterate through these properties via RTTI without knowing anything about the property and its index-values.
Because valid index-values must not be a sequence of integer-values this can't be possible. There might be properties with string-indexes or with object-references as index-value. And there is no mechanism in RTTI to query valid index-values wich could be used for an iteration.